# Find projective matrix with given null space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> Find an $n \times n$ projective matrix, $P$, such that its null space is spanned by vector $(1,1,...,1)^T$.

My attempt at solution:
A projective matrix is a matrix such that $P^2=P$ and $P^T=P$, i.e., it is a symmetric matrix, whose square is itself. 
Now by rank-nullity theorem, we know that $P$ is supposed to have $(n-1)$ linearly independent columns. So my solution would be the following $n \times n$ matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -1\\
&&& \vdots &&&\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

It easy to see that the null space is indeed given by $(1,1,1,...,1)^T$. On the other hand, $P^2=P$, which satisfies one of the requirements of being a projective matrix. However, I can’t think of any way of making this a symmetric matrix.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to math.se! [Here is a page on how to typeset math here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $P^2=P$, you have a perfectly good projection matrix. However, the definition of “projective matrix” that you have also requires that $P^T=P$, which makes it specifically an *orthogonal* projection. For that, the column space of the matrix must be the orthogonal complement of the null space.

There are several ways that you might construct such a matrix. A somewhat brute-force method is to find a basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}\}$ for the orthogonal complement of $W=\operatorname{span}\{(1,1,\dots,1)^T\}$. Assemble these vectors and $w=(1,1,\dots,1)^T$ itself into a matrix $B$. The desired projective matrix is then $$B\begin{bmatrix}I_{n-1}&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}B^{-1}.$$ (Do you see why?) Note that the non-zero rows of the matrix that you’ve constructed are a basis for $W^\perp$.

A simpler way is to observe that orthogonal projections onto $W$ and $W^\perp$ are complementary in the sense that if $P$ is the orthogonal projection onto $W$, then $I-P$ is the orthogonal projection onto $W^\perp$. Since $W$ is one-dimensional, the orthogonal projection matrix onto this subspace is quite easy to construct: the projection of a vector $v$ onto $w$ is ${w^Tv \over w^Tw}w = {ww^T\over w^Tw}v$, so the projection matrix onto $W^\perp$ is $I-{ww^T\over w^Tw}$. This is clearly symmetric, as required. For the vector in your problem, this will be $I_n-\frac1n\mathbb 1_n$, where $\mathbb 1_n$ is the $n\times n$ matrix of all $1$’s, i.e., $P$ has $(n-1)/n$ down its main diagonal and $-1/n$ elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The projection that you are looking for is $Px = x - \frac 1{\|v\|^2}\langle x,v\rangle v$, i.e.,
$$
P = I - \frac{vv^T}{v^Tv},
$$
where $v = (1,1,\ldots,1)^T$.